# Content that appears as you scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to get with jQuery the effect of this web page to "load" the content as you scroll. Example:
[enter link description here](https://conference.awwwards.com/speakers?facebook-likes)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= 50) {
   $(".row").addClass("active");
}
else {
$(".row").removeClass("active");
}
```

});

I have a codepen with a global efect but i would like to do with each panel. My idea is that the panels go loading loading in different heights of the scroll like in the web of the example 
[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/isbell/pen/YZjgpx)

Comment: I personally would advise you not to use a hardcode value to compare with the scroll position. This may work fine on one resolution, and you'll have hardcoded the correct value, but when a tablet or phone scrolls, the hardcoded value will not be the correct time to execute that code.
You could use jquery to get the Y-coordinates of the components you want to show, or you could use a [plugin](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) that tells you when the element is in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a plugin for it? You can try this: 
[animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)